# Refresh view or remove subviews ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a scene where the user can swipe over the screen to browse between posts. The post can be both an image with text or just a note, and the view is altered depending on which one occurs.

The getting process works just perfect. It gets the right post whether i swipe right or left. The problem is that the old view wont disappear and the views are overlapping. This is especially bothering when you go from a note to a photo or vice versa since the sizes ar different...

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@" GETRESULT %@   POSTNUMBER %d", getResult, postNumber);
Post *postInfo = [[Post alloc] init];

postInfo = [getResult objectAtIndex:postNumber];

UITextView *postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

NSString *getImageString = postInfo.attachments;
if(getImageString){
    postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
    [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 320, 280, 80)];
    NSLog(@"IMG1");
}else {
    postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
    [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 240)];
    NSLog(@"TEXT1");
}
[self.view addSubview:postText];
SHOWHUD(self.view);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getImageString];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 300)];
        [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [imgView setImage:img];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];
        HIDEHUD(self.view);
    });
});


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizerRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[recognizerLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizerLeft];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
NSLog(@"SWIPE RIGHT");
if(postNumber > 0){
    postNumber--;
    Post *postInfo = [[Post alloc] init];

    postInfo = [getResult objectAtIndex:postNumber];

    UITextView *postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    NSString *getImageString = postInfo.attachments;
    if(getImageString){
        [postText removeFromSuperview];
        postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
        [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 320, 280, 80)];
        NSLog(@"IMG1");
    }else {
        [postText removeFromSuperview];
        postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
        [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 240)];
        NSLog(@"TEXT1");
    }
    [self.view addSubview:postText];
    SHOWHUD(self.view);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        if (getImageString) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getImageString];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 300)];
        [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [imgView setImage:img];
        }else {
            [imgView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
            [self.view addSubview:imgView];
            HIDEHUD(self.view);
        });
    });
}

}

- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
NSLog(@"SWIPE LEFT");
if(postNumber < [getResult count] - 1){
    postNumber++;

    Post *postInfo = [[Post alloc] init];

    postInfo = [getResult objectAtIndex:postNumber];

    UITextView *postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    NSString *getImageString = postInfo.attachments;
    if(getImageString){
        [postText removeFromSuperview];
        postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
        [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 320, 280, 80)];
        NSLog(@"IMG1");
    }else {
        [postText removeFromSuperview];
        postText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        postText.text = postInfo.noteText;
        [postText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 240)];
        NSLog(@"TEXT1");
    }
    [self.view addSubview:postText];
    SHOWHUD(self.view);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        if(getImageString){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getImageString];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 300)];
        [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [imgView setImage:img];
        }else {
            [imgView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
            [self.view addSubview:imgView];
            HIDEHUD(self.view);
        });
    });

}
}
```

At first i only increased postNumber and called viewDidLoad in the swipe actions. That gave me the exact same result though... This is only one of countless trial and error attempts, and I'm sorry this is among the messier ones...

Would greatly appreciate it if anyone got a solution.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: which of your old view-imgView or postText or both is not getting removed?

Comment: @aj. Neither of them are getting removed. Guess it would be something with the way I'm removing it...

Comment: @DavidH I'm sorry David. I haven't had to many questions yet which make one question have a big impact on the statistics.
In many of the cases though, someone have given me a lead which later led me to solve the issue, but since it wasn't the right answer for the question I couldn't check it. That would make it pretty confusing other people searching huh?
I have explained the issue and thanked the people who put down time in every case though.

Comment: Ok so I feel like a total retard... I couldn't remove the variables from the superview because I did it in a new instance of viewDidLoad.
I tried to do so before calling viewDidLoad this time and it worked!

@DavidH 's post made me think too, and since I can't find anything but positive consequences from it, I will check whoever posts this answer first. :)

Comment: When you find the answer to your problem yourself, put this in an answer, and then when SO lets you accept it, do so. You can get 100% this way. Many people don't know you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't remove the variables from the superview because I did it in a new instance of viewDidLoad. I tried to do so before calling viewDidLoad this time and it worked!

Sorry for wasting your time...

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
for (UIView * view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isEqual:postText]||[view isEqual:imgView]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I found another solution. The problem was that I tried to remove the view in a new instance of viewDidLoad which didn't have any effect...
Sorry for wasting your time... :/